# Error with chromedriver version. Protractor require 2.31

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I think the Protractor is looking for the last available version of chromedriver, 2.31. The version was release the 22th of July 2017, 2 days ago. I cannot use this version because it is not compatible with my centos version (GLIBC_2.18).

Any way the chrome site says that the last release is the chromedriver 2.30.
So why protractor try to use the 2.31 ? This version is not installed.
Is there a way to force the use of a specific version ?

Thanks.

Node Version: v8.1.3
Protractor Version: Version 5.1.2
Chrome version: Google Chrome 59.0.3071.115
Angular Version: 1.5.9
Browser(s): Chrome
Operating System and Version
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
Release:    7.3.1611
Codename:   Core

Protractor configuration file:

```
module.exports = {
    // This will automatically use jasmine latest
    framework: 'jasmine',
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    getPageTimeout: 20000,
    allScriptsTimeout: 22000,
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        realtimeFailure: true,
        includeStackTrace: true,
        isVerbose: true,
    },
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: ['--no-sandbox'],
        },
        loggingPrefs: {driver: 'ALL', server: 'ALL', browser: 'ALL'},
    },
    ...
};
```

Protractor status:

> [root@protractor]# webdriver-manager status
>   
> [14:21:22] I/status - selenium standalone version available: 3.4.0 [last]
>   
> [14:21:22] I/status - chromedriver version available: 2.30 [last]
>   
> [14:21:22] I/status - geckodriver version available: v0.18.0 [last]
>   
> [14:21:22] I/status - android-sdk is not present
>   
> [14:21:22] I/status - appium is not present

Error:

```
[14:19:22] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[14:19:22] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[14:19:22] E/launcher - The driver executable does not exist: /root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.31
[14:19:22] E/launcher - WebDriverError: The driver executable does not exist: /root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.31
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:505:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:440:13)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:169:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:777:24)
    at Function.createSession (/root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:709:29)
    at createDriver (/root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:167:33)
    at Builder.build (/root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:623:16)
    at Hosted.getNewDriver (/root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:53:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
    at q.then.then (/root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29)
    at _fulfilled (/root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
[14:19:22] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

Hello,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update: ng e2e & protractor are now working!

I also had the same problem this morning. My current solution is:

```
rm -rf ./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/* #Manually clean
./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager clean #webdriver clean
mkdir ./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver #Fix a silly issue with webdriver trying to move this folder when it doesn't exist
./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=2.30 #Get the specific version
ng e2e --webdriver-update false #run npm without updating chromedriver
```

So therefore my package.json looks like so:

```
"pree2e": "rm -rf ./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/* && ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager clean && mkdir ./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver && node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=2.30",
"e2e": "ng e2e -e mock --webdriver-update false --progres false --watch false",
```

Comment: Hi Taylor, I did this but I still get the same error. I install protractor with **npm install** then use **webdriver-manage clean** and **webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=2.30**. But I still get **The driver executable does not exist** with a reference to **chromedriver_2.31**. Weird

Comment: I saw the same thing until i did the webdriver-manager clean. I'm going to keep investigating.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I do the following and it works

```
webdriver-manager update
webdriver-manager clean
webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=2.30
```

And then I start selenium server with force versions.chrome. If I don't specify this option, webdriver-manager still use chromedriver_2.31.

```
webdriver-manager start --versions.chrome=2.30
```

Comment: What about ng e2e? How will ng e2e try to start chrome driver again? Do you need to do a `webdriver-manager stop`?

Comment: I don't use `ng e2e` for launch tests. In fact I don't have to do `webdriver-manager stop` since it is launched from a docker container. I just changed the Dockerfile with the previous cmds and it start a new container. But your answer do the same thing!

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue this morning, i updated the selenium driver with `webdriver-manager update`enter, once the drivers are updated enter `webdriver-manager start` then this issue got resolved. Give it a try and let me know the result.

Comment: webdriver-manager update grabs the wrong chromdriver (2.31). To fix the issue we need chromedriver_2.30

Answer (score 0):

When chrome version and webdriver version is mis matched, this can be solved with picking the exact version of the webdriver-manager. For example:

```
webdriver-manager clean && webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=2.42
```

The error message is much improved now.

```
[11:42:19] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[11:42:19] E/launcher - session not created: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615279 (12b89733300bd268cff3b78fc76cb8f3a7cc44e5),platform=Linux 4.4.0-141-generic x86_64)
[11:42:19] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615279 (12b89733300bd268cff3b78fc76cb8f3a7cc44e5),platform=Linux 4.4.0-141-generic x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/home/xyzzy/proj/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/home/xyzzy/proj/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/home/xyzzy/proj/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/home/xyzzy/proj/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (/home/xyzzy/proj/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (/home/xyzzy/proj/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/direct.js:77:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/home/xyzzy/proj/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
    at q.then.then (/home/xyzzy/proj/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29)
    at _fulfilled (/home/xyzzy/proj/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/xyzzy/proj/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/xyzzy/proj/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /home/xyzzy/proj/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (/home/xyzzy/proj/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/home/xyzzy/proj/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:696:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
[11:42:19] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

Comment: check this blog- [protractor-error-resolution](https://khyatisehgal.wordpress.com/2019/05/27/protractor-session-not-created-chrome-version-must-be-between-70-and-73/)